# How can I open multiple task managers in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, task-manager

I can open one task manager.  Ctrl-Shift-Escape

I want to open another, so I can show one tab in one and another tab in another.

But when I do ctrl-shift-escape again, it just pulls up the one I already opened.

I'm sure in the past there have been times when i've done it.

How does one do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally you can't.

But take a look at http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/61970/Running-multiple-instances-of-Task-Manager

**added by barlop**

that EXE does it(the zip extracts to xTaskMgr.exe) it launches a new task manager

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/winsdk/xTaskMgr/xTaskMgr-sample.zip

Comment: link is broken!